# Symfony Newb Routing Issue

Tags: symfony

I have just started using Symfony and I am having a routing problem. Here is the routing fromt the controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/social/{name}/", name="_speed1")
 * @Route("/social/drivers/")
 * @Route("/social/drivers/{name}/", name="_driver")
 * @Route("/social/", name="_speed")
 * @Template()
 */
public function unlimitedAction()
{
```

If I go to speed/social/ or speed/social/bob or speed/social/drivers/ or speed/social/drivers/bob all of those pages render with no problem. However I need the name being passed in so I changed

```
public function unlimitedAction()
{
```

to

```
public function unlimitedAction($name)
{
```

If I go to speed/social/drivers/ or speed/social/drivers/bob it returns fine. However, if I go to speed/social/ then I get the following error:

```
Controller "MyBundle\Controller\DefaultController::unlimitedAction()" 
requires that you provide a value for the "$name" argument (because there is 
no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).
```

I can't understand why it works for one route but not the other.

So my question is, how can I acheive my routing so that I can go to:

```
speed/social/
speed/social/drivers/
speed/social/drivers/bob
```

And be able to pass the variable to the action without error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: you have to provide a default value for `name` parameter, for each route without the `{name}` parameter in the url. I can't test it right now and I can't remember the syntax when using annotations, but should be something like this:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/social/{name}/", name="_speed1", defaults={"name"=null})
 * @Route("/social/drivers/{name}/", name="_driver", defaults={"name"=null})
 * @Template()
 */
public function unlimitedAction($name)
{
}
```

This way you should be able to call `/social/` and `/social/foo` as well as `/social/drivers/` and `/social/drivers/foo`.

**But, really, this is not the right way to go**. Just define more actions, each binded to a single route:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/social", name="social_index")
 * @Template()
 */
public function socialIndexAction() { } // /social

/**
 * @Route("/social/{name}", name="social_show")
 * @Template()
 */
public function socialShowAction($name) { } // /social/foo
```

As a general rule, each method (each action) should be focused to do just one thing and should be as short as possible. Use services and make your controllers do what they are supposed to do: understand user input, call services and show views.

Comment: I think you can also use `unlimitedAction($name = null)` but as you said, this is not recommend.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you, I have been ReadingTFM but your answers really help make it all a lot more clear!